# How to make URL for column cells in CDE table component?

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I am making a dashboard with table component. I want to make URL for records in table like in this link [How to make URL for records in CDE table component?](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?157344-How-to-make-URL-for-records-in-CDE-table-component)

I apply the similar function and apply it in the "Post execution" in my table component instead of  in "Draw Function". (Because it is not working when i put it in "Draw Function"). It works in the first page of the table component. But on second page and third page, it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out. I change the column type to "formattedText " and wrote js function for add-in options: return text format with url  `"<a href='" + your url + "'><div style='color:blue'>"+cell value+"</div></a>"`. Then call this function in "pre execution".